# subprocess stdin buffer not flushing on newline with bufsize=1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pipe, subprocess, python-3.3

I have two small python files, the first reads a line using `input` and then prints another line

```
a = input()
print('complete')
```

The second attempts to run this as a subprocess

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('./simp.py',
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        bufsize=1)
print('writing')
proc.stdin.write(b'hey\n')
print('reading')
proc.stdout.readline()
```

The above script will print "writing" then "reading" but then hang.  At first I thought this was a stdout buffering issue, so I changed `bufsize=1` to `bufsize=0`, and this does fix the problem.  However, it seems it's the stdin that's causing the problem.

With `bufsize=1`, if I add `proc.stdin.flush()` below the write, the process continues.  Both of these approaches seem clumsy since (1) unbuffered streams are slow (2) adding flushes everywhere is error-prone.  Why does the above `write` not flush on a newline?  The docs say that `bufsize` is used when creating stdin, stdout, and stderr stream for the subprocess, so what's causing the write to not flush on the newline?

Comment: Curious indeed. `bufsize=1` works fine on python 2.x.

Comment: it is a [bug in Python 3](http://bugs.python.org/issue21332). It is fixed [for text mode](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/763d565e5840). See [subprocess line-buffering only works in universal newlines mode](http://bugs.python.org/issue21471)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/subprocess.html): *"1 means line buffered (only usable if universal_newlines=True i.e., in a text mode)"*. This works:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen('./simp.py',
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                        bufsize=1,
                        universal_newlines=True)

print('writing')
proc.stdin.write('hey\n')
print('reading')
proc.stdout.readline()
```

Comment: It doesn't work in Python 3.4.1 and Python 3.4.2 (the current version) due to [the fix introduced by issue21396](http://bugs.python.org/issue21396). It is fixed in [issue21332](http://bugs.python.org/issue21332) (the quote from the docs is introduced by [the fix](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/763d565e5840))