# subprocess.Popen bufsize=1 being ignored

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I'm having a similar problem described here:
[subprocess stdin buffer not flushing on newline with bufsize=1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571305/subprocess-stdin-buffer-not-flushing-on-newline-with-bufsize-1)

My script is not outputting line by line when I specify bufsize=1. It's infact outputting when the buffer fills. I want to read line by line in realtime.

I've tried the below on Linux Mint and CentOS 7. test.py is what I run, it calls the 'script' file which is executable.

**test.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess
import sys

process = subprocess.Popen('/root/script',bufsize=1, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,close_fds=True, universal_newlines=True)

for line in iter(process.stdout.readline, b''):
   print line
```

**script**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import time
for i in range(0,999999):
    print str('This is a short line, ' + str(i) + '\n')
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

This outputs large numbers of lines at once with pauses between the output. The first large chunk ends at line 154

However, If I make the output line much larger in the script file:

```
print str('This is a long line................................................................................................. ' + str(i) + '\n')
```

The first large chunk ends at line 66

Why is my buffer size being ignored?

Comment: which python version are you using precisely?

Comment: @Bakuriu  2.7.5 on CentOS 7, 2.7.6 on Mint.

Comment: Your `test.py` is wrong. It should be `Popen(['/root/script'], ...)` not `Popen('/root/script',...)`

Comment: @Bakuriu That part is not wrong. I'm only passing in one item to execute without arguments for that item so I don't need to use a list.